# Overriding Save method or adding Saving event with EF4

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Whats an easy (less code) way to add business logic to a 'code first' model to execute before its saved to the database?

E.g. given the [Albums model from the music store example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-3)

```
public class Album
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; private set;}
}
```

e.g. if we add a LastUpdated property to the example, how can we ensure it's automatically set if the entity is updated - perhaps on a save using someting like

```
private void album_OnSave()
{
   this.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [MSDN - EF4 How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx)

Comment: I've got to say this seems overly complex - this is on the context, the code is not in the model which doesn't seem great - I want my model code and rules in the damn model.

Answer (score 1):

LastUpdated has to be part of the model. For making sure the property is up to date I would use a repository and the functions that insert or update the album should set LastUpdated.

Comment: I am aware that LastUpdated has to be part of the model - have edited q to be clearer on that. Not sure what you mean by repository etc - isn't one of the points of EF that you don't have to do that sort of thing, just change the properties and it takes care of persistance?

Comment: In a lot of examples in MVC repositories are used. You are free not to use them but it would make other layers of your application not so independent anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to create a trigger during db creation that updates the LastUpdated column.

Comment: Didn't really want to use triggers because database specific and not visible in model and not correct place for business logic (LastUpdated) is just one example - triggers could get messy for more complex examples.